# Passing go -ldflags as an argument to Dockerfile

Tags: bash, go, dockerfile, quoting, go-build

I have a Dockerfile where I'm building the image from go source and I need to pass the `-ldflags` as an argument to the `go build` command. Below is a snippet of the Dockerfile:

```
// from statement and other stuff
...
# Build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -o manager main.go
```

which I changed to following:

```
// from statement and other stuff
...
ARG GO_FLAGS
# Build
# Below line throws error
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build ${GO_FLAGS} -a -o manager main.go
# Below works though
# RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-X <package-path>.BuildVersion=0.1.1-1" -a -o manager main.go
```

and I'm building docker image using:

```
docker build --build-arg GO_FLAGS='-ldflags "-X '<package-path>.BuildVersion=0.1.1-1'"' -t controller:test .
```

However, I'm getting below error:

```
[builder 15/15] RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-X <package-path>.BuildVersion=0.1.1-1" -a -o manager main.go:
0.607 invalid value "\"-X" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
0.607 usage: go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]
0.607 Run 'go help build' for details.
------
Dockerfile:42
--------------------
  40 |
  41 |     # Build
  42 | >>> RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build ${GO_FLAGS} -a -o manager main.go
```

I initially thought that this could be due to quotes not being handled properly by the shell. However, I've tried using multiple ways of quoting(single/double) and still see the same issue. I'm relatively new to `docker` and `go` so I'm not able to figure out what's causing this issue.

So, I want to know if there is a way to pass the build flags as argument to the Dockerfile?

Comment: Why the `-X`, did you try `docker build --build-arg GOFLAGS='"yourpackage.BuildVersion=0.1.1-1"'  .` ?

Comment: shell quoting can be tricky.  I suggest you change `${GOFLAGS}` to `"${GOFLAGS}"` and `--build-arg GOFLAGS='"-X <package-path>.BuildVersion=0.1.1-1"'` to `--build-arg 'GOFLAGS="-X <package-path>.BuildVersion=0.1.1-1"`

Comment: @mpromonet I actually need to pass the `ldflags` (including ldflags itself) as an argument to dockerfile from a makefile as the ldflags is used in other places as well. This is what I was trying to verify before I pass it as an arg from makefile.

Comment: @Cheshar but go build ldflags doesnot have -X, format is `-ldflags '[pattern=]arg list'` see https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go